# how to escape # in my expect scipt while calling password from another file

Tags: special-characters, expect

I have few queries in expect..

I'm using expect script and I need to pick the password from a different file..

1) I'm able to do it.. but for one of my connection the password starts with # (hash mark) hence its picked.. I use the below command

```
set pwfl [open "/tmp/test/m1"]
set pw [read "$pwfl"]
```

2) how to set the format for date in the log file.. I use the below.. 
[exec date]_log file.. but the date format alone needs to be changed

## !/usr/bin/expect -f

set pwfl1 [open "/tmp/test/m2"]
set pw1 [read  "$pwfl1"]
set pwfl3 [open "/tmp/test/m4"]
set pw3 [read "$pwfl2"]
log_file [exec date]_Ext_Push_FTP.log
spawn sftp -v -o Port=122 -o IdentityFile=/tmp/test/SSH_PrivateKey_SFTPTesting.openssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes t_rt_ext_push_sftppak_p@************
set timeout 15
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/tmp/test/SSH_PrivateKey_SFTPTesting.openssh':" {send "$pw3\r"}
set timeout 30
expect "t_rt_ext_push_sftppak_p@e********'s password:" {puts "$pw1\r"}
expect "sftp>" {send "put Sample_RT_Ext_Push_SFTPPAK.txt\r\n"}
expect "sftp>" {send "!echo Test file has been uploaded successfully by `whoami` at `date`  >> Ext_Push_SFTPPAK.ftp\r\n"}
expect "sftp>" {send "bye\r"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see you describing a problem. Is there an error?
2. use expect's builtin `timestamp` command:

   ```
   set log_file [timestamp -format {%Y%m%d_log.file}]     ;# => 20170714_log.file
   ```

Comment: I'm more worried abt 1st question.. can you help me with that?

Comment: what is the question? You don't say what problem you have.

Comment: I need to execute expect without showing password to others.. so I'm reading password from another file.. since the password start with # its not working

Comment: more details a.txt is file with password alone I need the expect to read the file for the password and then enter it.. but the password is starting with #

Comment: how to send ascii characters to expect file..

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the code you've shown that would be a problem for reading the # character from a file. What happens when you `puts ">$pw<"`? One thing you may have is the pw will might with a newline character (depending on how you created the pw file). You might want to `set pw [read -nonewline $pwfl]`